# Passing multiple config groups

Tags: fb-hydra

In my config.yaml, how to pass two datasets for e.g. cifar and cinic at once? Can I pass a multiple config groups to the defaults list?

This is for the case when I want to train my model on a mix of datasets, but I do not want to create a config group for every possible combination.

```
├── config.yaml
└── dataset
    ├──  cifar.yaml
    └── imagenet.yaml
    └── cinic.yaml
```

What I tried is as follows:

```
dataset: 
  - cifar
  - cinic
```

which resulted in following error:

`Could not load train_dataset/['cifar', 'cinic']. Available options 'cifar ... '`

Answer (score 1):

Currently config groups are mutually exclusive.
Support for this is planned for Hydra 1.1. See [issue 499](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/499).

One possible workaround is to put everything in the config and to use interpolation:

```yaml
all_datasets:
  imagenet:
    name: imagenet
  cifar10:
    name: cifar10

datasets:
  - ${all_datasets.imagenet}
  - ${all_datasets.cifar10}
```

This way you can override dataset to a different list of datasets from the command line (with the interpolation).

If you want to simplify the usage at the expense of some additional code, you can do something like:

```yaml
all_datasets:
  ...

datasets_list:
  - imagenet
  - cifar10

datasets: []
```

```py
@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
  for ds in cfg.datasets_list:
    cfg.datasets.append(cfg.all_datasets[ds])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

I didn't test this but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I made a suggestion on the GitHub issue that you opened.

Comment: Updated the answer with a couple of possible workaround. Be creative.

Comment: Yeah I did something similar of providing list of names of datasets and in my code I had path and other properties for each data. 

However, Can I  enable config group files with your method? If yes, then which directory they should be at. `all_datasets/imagenet.yaml`   
   
However, with with both these cases, which directory the config groups should be saved? What I mean is, for e.g. `imagenet` will  have different properties like `path` etc. At present they are inside dataset folder.

Comment: The proposed here is a workaround without using config groups exactly because of the limitations of config groups in 1.0. (mutually exclusive). You can include files unconditionally which might help:

https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/defaults#non-config-group-defaults

Comment: one more query @omry, there was a link to sample projects using Hydra on hydra.cc webpage but I am unable to find it. Is that removed? :/

Comment: I don't know what you mean. there are example applications in the repo (and there are multiple links to them it from the website). There are also the dependent repositories GitHub is tracking: https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/network/dependents?package_id=UGFja2FnZS01ODkxMjQ0ODE%3D